# What is the right sentence to tell others my wife already delivered a baby

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

What is the right sentence to tell others my wife already delivered a baby

My wife already got delivered

or

My wife already delivered

or

is there any better way to communicate

Comment: It depends on whether she was an obstetrician or pregnant.

Comment: Can you give us some context for the situation where you want to use this sentence? Usually, *already* in this kind of sentence would indicate that the event happened surprisingly (to the listener) early.

Comment: If your friends already knew she was pregnant, just say "it's a boy/girl".

Comment: I would suggest using "gave birth" to avoid the issue. See [this article](https://www.plumtreebaby.com/blogs/news/17956548-deliver-vs-give-birth), including the footnote. The [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/deliver) offers both meanings.

Comment: My wife had her baby!  ... Our baby was born today at 3:05 am.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use delivered. The only way would be "My wife was delivered of a baby" and that sounds very dated.

"My wife has given birth." is a more normal phrasing. In speaking, something more direct is possible

"I'm a father!!"  is simple and direct.

In a formal announcement something like

> Tom and Mary are pleased to announce the birth of a daughter.
>
> The baby (or use the baby's name) was born at 3am on the 10th of April and weighed 2.9kg
>
> Mother and baby are both doing well" (this is a conventional formula to reassure that everything is fine)

Answer (score 0):

The baby got delivered.  Your wife delivered him/her.  The second construction is best.

Answer (score -2):

This is a highly pertinent question. The verb "to deliver" when related to childbirth is quite complex. Indeed there is a relevant previous question on EL & U namely [When did a mother giving birth become the deliverer and not the deliveree?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192818/when-did-a-mother-giving-birth-become-the-deliverer-instead-of-the-deliveree/192840#192840)

As the OED makes clear, deliver (when speaking of childbirth) has two distinct senses - 3a and 3b.

3a:

> To disburden (a woman) of the fœtus, to bring to childbirth; in 
>   pass., to give birth to a child or offspring. Rarely said of beasts. 
>   (The active is late and chiefly in obstetrical use.)

and in OED sense 3b:

> b. pass. Of the offspring: To be brought forth (lit. and fig.).

**Thus what happens is that the doctor/midwife *delivers* the mother (sense 3a), and in sense 3b  the mother *delivers the baby*. And as you will see from the examples of 3a. the mother is often said to have been *delivered of her baby*. The point about *deliver* (when used in this way) is that it means to liberate or set free**

OED examples of 3a:

> c1325   Metr. Hom. 63   For than com tim Mari mild Suld be deliuerd of
>   hir child.
>
> a1400  (▸a1325)    Cursor Mundi (Fairf. 14) l. 5562   Þer wimmen..ar
>   deliuered be þaire awen sliȝt.
>
> 1480   Caxton Chron. Eng. lxxi. 53   Tyme come that she shold be
>   delyuered and bere a child.
>
> 1484   Caxton tr. Subtyl Historyes & Fables Esope i. ix   A bytche
>   which wold lyttre and be delyured of her lytyl dogges.
>
> 1568   E. Tilney Brief Disc. Mariage (new ed.) sig. Cviij   To have
>   thy wyfe with childe safely delyvered.
>
> a1616   Shakespeare Winter's Tale (1623) ii. ii. 28   She is,
>   something before her time, deliuer'd .
>
> 1676   J. Cooke Mellificium Chirurg. (ed. 3) 682   The third time they
>   sent, and beg'd I would deliver her.
>
> 1754–64   W. Smellie Treat. Midwifery I. Introd. 70   A better method
>   of delivering in laborious and preternatural cases.
>
> 1805   Med. & Physical Jrnl. 14 521   By making an incision in the
>   urethra..the patient might be delivered.
>
> c1850   Arabian Nights (Rtldg.) 448   The queen..was in due time
>   safely delivered of a prince.

OED examples of 3b.

> 1581   G. Pettie tr. S. Guazzo Ciuile Conuersat. (1586) i. 12   All
>   beastes so soone as they are delivered from their dam get upon their
>   feete.
>
> 1609   Shakespeare Sonnets lxxvii. sig. F   Those children nurst,
>   deliuerd from thy  braine.
>
> a1616   Shakespeare Othello (1622) i. iii. 369   There are many euents
>   in the womb of Time, which will be deliuered .

**Hence, in direct answer to the question you could say "My wife was delivered of a baby daughter" (sense 3a); or - my wife delivered a baby daughter (sense 3b)**

Comment: This does a great job of explaining the definitions without actually answering the question. Do you think that either of the options listed are good ways of phrasing this sentence? Personally, I don't.